# Why is my comparison not producing the expected result?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm expecting this to output "Failed" but instead it outputs "Excellent", even though the value being compared doesn't match that comparison.

What's wrong with my code?

```js
let grade = 99;
if(140 <= grade <= 150) {
  console.log('Excellent');
}
else if(100 <= grade) {
  console.log('Very Good');
}
else if(grade < 100) {
  console.log('Failed');
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that "it doesn't work properly" is not a good explanation. Why doesn't it work? What is your desired output?

Comment: `if (grade >= 140) {console.log('Excellent');} else if (grade >=100) {console.log('Very Good');} else {console.log('Failed');}`

Comment: @WaisKamal I think this is a reasonable first post. We know what it's supposed to do, which is output 'Failed', and it's been understood and answered (correctly) by a few people already.

Comment: @mrblewog I actually just skimmed through the text not finding out a desired behaviour. Yes, it is clear here what the result should be, but it would be good for the OP to bear in mind stating the desired behaviour for future posts.

Answer (score 3):

This is not how multiple comparisons are made:

```
if (140 <= grade <= 150)
```

In this case the first half would evaluate to `true` or `false` and the rest would be something like `true <= 150` which makes little sense.

Instead, rather than think of it in terms of intuition, think of it in terms of combining logical operations.  The two operations you want are:

- `140 <= grade`
- `grade <= 150`

Combine those with the "and" operator:

```
if (140 <= grade && grade <= 150)
```

Result:

```js
let grade = 99;
if (140 <= grade && grade <= 150) {
  console.log('Excellent');
} else if(100 <= grade) {
  console.log('Very Good');
} else if(grade < 100) {
  console.log('Failed');
}
```

Comment: Side note: In the comparison `true <= 150` or `false <= 150`, `true` will behave like `1` and `false` will behave like `0`. Similar to how `true + 0` produces `1` and `false + 0` produces `0`. `true == 1`, `true > 0`, `false == 0`, `false < 1` will all result in `true`.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to check whether the grade is between 140 and 150 by `140 <= grade <= 150` then you are doing it the wrong way. This will evaluate `140 <= grade` first, which will return either zero or one, which will then be compared to 150 (and hence will always be smaller). You need to use two separate statements:

```
if(140 <= grade && grade <= 150) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this. You need to separate two condition which you provided in the first if statement.

```js
let grade = 99;     
if(140<= grade && grade <=150){
    console.log('Excellent');
  }
  else if(100<= grade){
    console.log('Very Good');
  }
  else if(grade < 100){
    console.log('Failed');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Expression `140 <= grade <= 150` is correct in mathematical form. In js you must write it as `140 <= grade && grade <=150`